# Como verificar uma posição nula no vetor

Tags: java, lista, array

Por que  fazer  `if(array[i] == null)` não está correto?

Qual seria o melhor jeito de verificar se aquele espaço do vetor está "vazio"?

Comment: Onde você viu dizendo que não está correto essa comparação? Se tiver dentro de um for, pode até não ser a melhor forma de se fazer, mas errada não estaria.

Comment: Qual que é o tipo do array? Para mim, a menos que o tipo base do array seja um tipo primitivo, isto está correto sim.

Comment: o vetor é do tipo int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há uma diferença fundamental entre uma matriz nula e uma matriz vazia . Este é um teste para nulo .

```
int arr[] = null;
if (arr == null) {
  System.out.println("array is null");
}
```

Para você verificar matriz é vazio use;

```
arr = new int[0];
if (arr.length == 0) {
 System.out.println("array is empty");
}
```

Uma definição alternativa de " vazio " é , se todos os elementos são nulos :

```
Object arr[] = new Object[10];
boolean empty = true;
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] != null) {
    empty = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Ou;

```
Object arr[] = new Object[10];
boolean empty = true;
for (Object ob : arr) {
  if (ob != null) {
    empty = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Elementos em matrizes primitivas não pode estar vazio . Eles sempre são inicializados para alguma coisa ( geralmente 0 para matrizes int , mas depende de como você declarar a matriz ) .

Se você declarar a matriz assim, por exemplo:

Referencia [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-we-check-for-null-array-in-java).

```
int [] myArray ;
myArray = new int[7] ;
```

Todos os elementos será o padrão para 0 .
Uma sintaxe alternativa para matrizes declarando é

```
int[] myArray = { 12, 7, 32, 15, 113, 0, 7 };
```

Onde os valores iniciais para uma matriz ( de tamanho sete neste caso ) são dadas nas chaves { }.

Referencia [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286161/how-can-i-see-if-an-element-in-an-int-array-is-empty).

Comment: Sua resposta está bem melhor agora. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Considerando o que você disse [neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136799/como-verificar-uma-posi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-nula-no-vetor/136809#comment283462_136799):

> o vetor é do tipo int – [Dr.G](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/45252/dr-g)

O problema é o seguinte:

O tipo do array é `int[]`. O que significa que `array[i]` é do tipo `int`. O problema é comparar `int` com `null`. Tipos primitivos nunca serão `null` e o compilador sabe disso. Por isso ele vai te dar um erro de compilação:

> ```
> incomparable types: int and <null>
> ```

Comment: mas tipo, vamos supor que eu tenha um vetor inteiro v[], aí eu adicionei 3 na posição 0, agora quero deletar o conteúdo da posição 0, ao meu ver deveria dizer que v[0] =  null,mas creio que isso esteja errado.
A intenção é tentar simular funções do ArrayList como add e remove com arrays comuns.

Comment: @Dr.G Não há como deletar-se posições em um array. Em um array cujo tipo base é um objeto, você pode definir uma posição como `null`, mas a posição continua existindo. No caso de um `int[]`, ele já vem preenchido automaticamente com um monte de zeros. É impossível em Java colocar-se `null` dentro de um `int[]`. Além disso, um array tem um tamanho fixo, independente de quantos ou quais elementos têm como conteúdo `null`. Acho que o que você precisa é de uma `java.util.List` e não de um array.

Comment: @Dr.G Internamente, o `ArrayList` mantém um contador de quantas posições no array foram utilizadas, o array interno pode ser (e frequente é) bem maior que esse contador. Os métodos do `ArrayList` não deixam que posições além do limite do tamanho do `ArrayList` (e não do array) sejam acessadas, mesmo se elas existirem no array. Quando o array interno é pequeno demais, ele cria um novo array com o dobro do tamanho, copia os elementos e descarta o array antigo. Para remover elementos, ele copia todos elementos subsequentes uma posição para trás e diminui o contador, colocando `null` só no fim.

Comment: valeu,era isso mesmo que eu queria saber